# PERL regex for discord id that ends after 4th digit

Tags: regex

I tried using this which appears to work..

^.*#[0-9]{4}$

test#1234

Except this also is accepted as valid input.

test#1234 #1234

How do I go about making it so that after the 4 digits no other characters will be accepted without hindering the initial match?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use:

```
$string =~ /^\D+#\d{4}$/
```

Where `\D` stands for any character that is not a digit.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use a negative lookahead which asserts that a `#1234` pattern does not occur after matching the first one:

```
^[^#]*#[0-9]{4}(?!.*#[0-9]{4}).*$
```

### Regex101

 

### Perl demo